# Voltage divider resistor PN balancing

Tags: analog, adc, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, error

Refer the representational schematics for voltage sensing by ADC (SAR). I read somewhere to balance the P and N lines add R3 = R1||R2. How come R1 and R2 parallel combination could be considered as contributing error voltage at P so that N has to be R3=R1||R2. Could somebody shed some light as to how the actual current path is balanced?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHmr6B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Nedd: Please do not answer the question in comments, as this bypasses the normal review process for answers, as [discussed in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have the equivalent of two voltage sources with **equal series resistances** (Thevenin sources) for each input.

The equivalent circuit of a voltages source combined with a voltage divider consisting of resistors R1 and R2 (that's what you have at the non-inverting input) is a Thevenin source with resistance \$R_{th} = R1 || R2\$.

I.e. both circuits in following diagram are equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJtWJJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the source at the inverting input should also have a series resistance \$R3 = R1 || R2\$.

Answer (score 2):

The extra equivalent resistor is an attempt to balance out slight input bias currents. Because op-amps are not perfect there can be small currents flowing into or out of the input pins. If there is equal resistance on both input pins (and the currents are equal) then there will be an equal voltage drop, thereby generating minimal output offset voltages.